# Please help to prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty {1\over a_n-1}<{2\over 7}$,in which $a_n=4n(n+1)$

Tags: inequality

Please help to prove this.

Suppose $a_n=4n(n+1)$,then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{1\over a_n-1}<{2\over7}.$$
Thanks.

Comment: did you try expanding $\frac{1}{4n^2 +4n -1}$ in partial fractions>

Comment: Yes. I tried ${1\over 4n^2+4n-1}<{1\over4}({1\over 2n-1}-{1\over 2n+3})$ and then proved the sum is less than ${1\over 3}$.

Comment: Jejeje...indeed, @Did. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$4n(n+1)-1=(2n+1)^2-2>(2n+1)^2-4=(2n+3)(2n-1)$$So, given sum is less than $$\frac{1}{7}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+3)(2n-1)}=\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\ge 2}\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+3}\right)=\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}\right)\\=\frac{1}{7}+\frac{2}{15}<\frac{2}{7}$$